# Copy page append javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I'w writting a simple web scraper, but I want user to be able to select elements he want's to scrap. Is there any way to do that without browser extentions? 
I'm trying to implement as a web application, but there are some cross-domain issues I'm facing in order to copy source. Is it possible to write in some other language like C#, with css selector?

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse HTML text with a parser.

In c# you have [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), that will allow you to achieve this.